# COM class factory error

Tags: vb.net, com, visual-studio-2005

I've been testing an application using my machine as a server, and everything's going fine with it, but when I try to set it up to run on the test server, I get this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Please check on your test server the registration of your com objects.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{xxxx}
```

Check, if your dll or exe  file is on the correct location on the hard drive.

Second: This link may help: http://support.software602.com/kb/view.aspx?articleID=987

Answer (score 1):

The error code translates to "class not registered".

Registering is usually done with "regsvr32 " when it is a DLL or via " /RegServer".

To avoid the described error message, please register on client and server.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this error sometimes with MSXML 4, especially when doing installation tests.

**Resolution:** deinstall and reinstall MSXML.