# COM class factory error

Tags: c#, com, clsid

I am getting the following error on my workstation when I am trying to work with a COM object.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in CarteGraphInterface.exe
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID
>   {3963F0F8-6B0C-4A65-90F4-F60168044014}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80040154.

I have read through [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218405/) here on SO and non of them have helped. That ID is not listed anywhere in the registry. Does it need to be added?

**Update:** A bit more information. When I choose "Add Reference..." in VS2008, the object is listed there (that is how I found it initially), and the source is listed as a *.exe. regsrv32 didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these solutions worked. I assume that they do not actually have APIs that could be used with .NET (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you need to register the COM DLL using

```
regsvr32.exe /i dllname
```

Try that first perhaps and see if that makes a difference.

EDIT: Don't know if you use this, but COM Explorer might be able to help you too. Try [the trial](http://com-explorer.en.softonic.com/) version to if it helps you with this problem.

EDIT: I've been trying to find out more about the error code, and the best I could find is [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201234), which clarifies that it must be the DLL which is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add reference to your project? When working with COM you almost always should add reference at "COM" tab (not at "Browse"), this ensures you will get a valid reference to a registered object, creating a new interop assembly. Though, if you have a registration problem, you most probably won't find required reference on COM tab.

First, it's very strange for a COM component to live in an executable file (though it's possible). Maybe this component wasn't supposed to be instantiated from another application, so all registration data had been removed? I would suggest contacting whomever you got this component from and ask for a registerable dll version.

Comment: It's an application I am trying to interface with. They have an "undocumented" API. I know they have one because they can "write custom programs" to do "whatever we want." I thought I would give it a shot to see if those COM objects I found could be used. The object browser shows exactly what I was looking for and started to interface with it. 

Could it be that it requires VB vs. C# or would the same result show up?